# how to use ActiveSheet variable?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path).ActiveSheet  <- error
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("aa.xlsx").Worksheets("bb")
```

it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

FYI `ThisWorkbook.Path` is the *folder location* for the workbook - you'd need `Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)` if you wanted to go that route (but you don't need to...)